# Groupby string in column name and plot

Tags: python, pandas

Reproducible:

```
 nan = np.NaN
    bynote = {'bynote_n1_trial_ms': {0: -18963961,
  1: 31992270,
  2: -13028311,
  3: 31992270,
  4: -13028311,
  5: -13028311},
 'bynote_n2_trial_ms': {0: nan,
  1: -13028311.0,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan},
 'bynote_n3_trial_ms': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'n1': {0: 60, 1: 60, 2: 60, 3: 40, 4: 40, 5: 30},
 'n2': {0: nan, 1: 40.0, 2: 40.0, 3: nan, 4: 30.0, 5: nan},
 'n3': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 30.0, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}}

    bynote = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(bynote)
```

I would like to plot a graph where the column n1, n2 etc. are the x values and bynote_n1_trial_ms, bynote_n2_trial_ms etc. are the corresponding y values.

Should I groupby a string (i.e n1 etc) somehow or how do I go about this?

Edit:

[image]

Each row *represents a separate plot* where the left DF is y and the right x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe is possible working with each DataFrame [separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55449828/2901002):

```
df1 = bynote.iloc[:, 3:]
df2 = bynote.iloc[:, :3]
```

So use loop by zipped columns with `plt.plot()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for x, y in zip(df1.columns, df2.columns):
    plt.plot(df1[x], df2[y])

plt.show()
```

EDIT:

```
for x, y in zip(df1.columns, df2.columns):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(df1[x], df2[y])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see edit. Each row should be a separate plot.

Comment: This returns KeyError: 'n1'. I applied it thus:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    for x, y in zip(chunk.columns, bynote.columns):
        bynote.plot(x = x, y = y)
    
    plt.show()

Comment: Index(['bynote_n1_trial_ms', 'bynote_n2_trial_ms', 'bynote_n3_trial_ms'], dtype='object')

Comment: @syntheso - Then is necessary `plt.figure()` in loop, answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

try plots overlaid by defining x and y as arrays of the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


nan = np.NaN
bynote = {'bynote_n1_trial_ms': {0: -18963961,
  1: 31992270,
  2: -13028311,
  3: 31992270,
  4: -13028311,
  5: -13028311},
 'bynote_n2_trial_ms': {0: nan,
  1: -13028311.0,
  2: nan,
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan},
 'bynote_n3_trial_ms': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan},
 'n1': {0: 60, 1: 60, 2: 60, 3: 40, 4: 40, 5: 30},
 'n2': {0: nan, 1: 40.0, 2: 40.0, 3: nan, 4: 30.0, 5: nan},
 'n3': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: 30.0, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan}}

bynote = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(bynote)


plt.figure()

plt.scatter(bynote['n1'], bynote['bynote_n1_trial_ms'])
plt.scatter(bynote['n2'], bynote['bynote_n2_trial_ms'])
plt.scatter(bynote['n3'], bynote['bynote_n3_trial_ms'])

plt.show()
```